# How to identify using jQuery which button was clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML table with multiple buttons:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button id="theBtn" key="9cb4064c-0fd8-454c-bfbc-bfaf0741c0e8" class="icons icon_hardwaresoftware icons0500 iconedit"></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button id="theBtn" key="04e25e95-7aec-4d90-b8c0-f1d706e59a56" class="icons icon_hardwaresoftware icons0500 iconedit"></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button id="theBtn" key="a834a18b-5c9f-451c-a414-07becdbf728c" class="icons icon_hardwaresoftware icons0500 iconedit"></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have a single function defined to handle the onClick event:

```
theBtn.onclick = function() {
    var key = theBtn.attr('name');
    ...
}
```

but the problem is that I don't know which of those buttons was clicked. All the **Stackoverflow** examples read by me have two things what differ from my situation:

- the jQuery class select has a **single** value, mine has **four** values
- the HTML element is a submit type input element, mine is a **button**

So, I am stuck.

Comment: `this` should be the actual element that invoked the event (edit, I didn't notice those were id's and not classes. don't do that)

Comment: How is this even working? Either `theBtn` is a jQuery object then there's no `onclick` property, or it is a DOM node then there's an `onclick` property but no `.attr()` method -> [Events | jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/events/)

Comment: You should not have multiple iteration of a same ID inside the same page.

Comment: ^ Quentin is correct. ID's **must be unique**. If you'd like the elements to share a common identifier, consider giving them all a matching `class` instead. You can add an event to all of them by doing `$(".buttonClass").click(function() { ... });`, where `buttonClass` is the matching class you've given them. Inside the function, you could use `$(this)` to refer to the exact button that was clicked, as rlemon states above.

Comment: @rlemon If this code would work, then `this` would only be the clicked element when TO would use vanilla `.addEventListener()` or one of the many jQuery methods (`.click()`, `.on()`, ...). With the `onclick` property of a DOM node `this` will be the `window` or `undefined`

Comment: @Andreas the question is full of surprises, if theBtn has .attr we can assume it is a jQuery object. however then the onclick wouldn't register, unless they have an alias for that. been a while since I looked at jQuery

Comment: As I said, the value of CSS class has more values and specifying all them has no effect.

Comment: -> [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: I know that I should avoid to use the same ID. In fact that HTML code comes from a remote system as a response to an AJAX call.

Answer (score 1):

The main concept of ID is that it should be unique.

Also, instead of binding a event listener to ID, use class.

On callback "`this`" holds the scope of the element clicked as given in the code snippet for your reference

```js
$('.iconedit').on('click', function(){

console.log(this);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button id="theBtn" key="9cb4064c-0fd8-454c-bfbc-bfaf0741c0e8" class="icons icon_hardwaresoftware icons0500 iconedit first"></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button id="theBtn" key="04e25e95-7aec-4d90-b8c0-f1d706e59a56" class="icons icon_hardwaresoftware icons0500 iconedit second"></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button id="theBtn" key="a834a18b-5c9f-451c-a414-07becdbf728c" class="icons icon_hardwaresoftware icons0500 iconedit third"></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In first place you cannot have the same id in the same page, thats why is a ID, if you have multiple buttons that make the same action you have to set a same class, like class="theBtn"

and this little snippet can help you

```js
let btn = document.getElementsByClassName("theBtn");

for (var i = 0; i<btn.length; i++){
    btn[i].onclick = function() {
        console.log(this.getAttribute('key'));
    }
}
```

Or with jQuery

```
$(".theBtn").on("click", function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('key'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

So, taking in consideration your tips, suggestions and critics I ended with this solution:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( 'button.icons.icon_hardwaresoftware.icons0500.iconedit' ).on("click", function(){
        console.log($(this).attr('key'));
    })
});
```

Instead of that unique ID, by using all CSS class names, I can read out the value of the **key** attribute for the clicked button.